# MediaStyle not appearing properly

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to create notification for my music player application and I have a trouble of making use of media style. First of all bitmap I put in setLargeIcon is not appearing and notification only shows buttons(they work)

This is base method I use to set metadata of song into notification:

```
    public static NotificationCompat.Builder from(
        Context context, MediaSessionCompat mediaSession) {
    MediaControllerCompat controller = mediaSession.getController();
    MediaMetadataCompat mediaMetadata = controller.getMetadata();
    MediaDescriptionCompat description = mediaMetadata.getDescription();

    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "MusicID");
    builder
            .setContentTitle(description.getTitle())
            .setContentText(description.getSubtitle())
            .setSubText(description.getDescription())
            .setLargeIcon(description.getIconBitmap())
            .setContentIntent(controller.getSessionActivity())
            .setVisibility(NotificationCompat.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
    return builder;
}
```

That's how I create a notification

```
    private Notification showPlayingNotification() {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = MediaStyleHelper.from(MediaPlaybackService.this, mMediaSessionCompat);
    if (builder == null) {
        return null;
    }
    builder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(android.R.drawable.ic_media_previous, "Previous", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_PREVIOUS)));
    builder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(android.R.drawable.ic_media_pause, "Pause", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE)));
    builder.addAction(new NotificationCompat.Action(android.R.drawable.ic_media_next, "Next", MediaButtonReceiver.buildMediaButtonPendingIntent(this, PlaybackStateCompat.ACTION_SKIP_TO_NEXT)));
    builder.setStyle(new android.support.v4.media.app.NotificationCompat.MediaStyle().setShowActionsInCompactView(0, 1, 2).setMediaSession(mMediaSessionCompat.getSessionToken()));
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    return builder.build();
}
```

[image: Notification I'm getting]

So the problem is that bitmap I'm setting in my other method is not appearing at all and whole style looks off.